# как получить данные с .equals\contains()

Tags: java, javafx

у меня есть 2 текста которые сравниваются, и если один не сравнивается с другим, нужно вывести тот КУСОК ТЕКСТА, который не сравнивается. Например new file-1 текст\ new file jojo-2 текст, у нас не сравнивается jojo, нужно чтобы это вывелось.
h

Comment: equals и contains вам здесь не помогут. Подозреваю, что давший вам это задание, ожидает от вас алгоритм динамического программирования.

Comment: не, я сам себе такое задание дал, я свою прогу мучу

Comment: Ну, тогда могу посоветовать "[Алгоритмы Руководство по разработке](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6290126/)" Стивена Скиены, в частности главу 8.

Comment: https://google.gik-team.com/?q=java+diff